# How can I create a window with transparent background with swift on osx?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to create an osx/cocoa application on my mac, which does something very simple: Display a text string on my mac, with no background. Ultimately this will be a timer which displays as an overlay on top of other windows, without being too intrusive.

I tried setting `window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1.0, green:0.5, blue:0.5, alpha: 0.5)` (see the alpha is 0.5), in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` but this doesn't turn it into something remotely transparent.

Any good soul wants to suggest a way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles

Answer (score 22, accepted):

NSWindow has a property 'opaque' which it is true by default.

> The value of this property is true when the window is opaque;
>   otherwise, false.

Just change it to false:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    view.window?.opaque = false
    view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
}
```

**Swift 4 update:** `opaque` has been renamed [isOpaque](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419086-isopaque)

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    view.window?.isOpaque = false
    view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5) 
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Make the window non-opaque, and give it a clear background:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    window.opaque = false
    window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: @sagism Why is this answer marked as correct if it was posted more than 3 hours later than mine?

Comment: @LeoDabus: simply setting the window's ``opacity`` to false isn't enough to get the effect sagism is after (I tried it); you need to change the background color also.

Comment: this is not true considering the color already has alpha set to 0.5, window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1.0, green:0.5, blue:0.5, alpha: 0.5) so it has already transparency. If he wanted full transparency all he needed to do is set alpha to 0.0 with ANY color

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, my bad, I thought more recent answers show up at the top, so I thought I was accepting the first one. Just corrected this.

Answer (score 7):

A little update for **Swift 3**

A window subclass example with comment:

```
class customWindow: NSWindow {
    
    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindowStyleMask, backing bufferingType: NSBackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: style, backing: bufferingType, defer: flag)
        
        // Set the opaque value off,remove shadows and fill the window with clear (transparent)
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.hasShadow = false
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        
        // Change the title bar appereance
        self.title = "My Custom Title"
        //self.titleVisibility = .hidden
        self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true


        
        
    }
```

- More on Title Bar appereance here [Title Bar and Toolbar Showcase](https://github.com/robin/TitlebarAndToolbar)

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3/4

```
self.window?.isOpaque = false
self.window?.hasShadow = false
self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049936/3389077) for **Swift 5**:

```swift
import Cocoa

final class CustomWindow: NSWindow {
    
    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindow.StyleMask, backing bufferingType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: style, backing: bufferingType, defer: flag)
        isOpaque = false
        hasShadow = false
        titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        backgroundColor = .clear
        title = "Title"
    }
}
```