# How to make window transparent in osx swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a empty created project in Xcode.

When I press run button, it displays a window. How can I change it's appearance like transparency of window etc.

I've searched a lot but everyone uses a `window` variable to change like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34531118/4859791) but how can I create `NSWindow` instance?

I'm new to mac app development. So can anyone write a detailed answer?

Thank you!

Comment: @LeoDabus yes..

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. It works! Can you post it as answer so that it will help other readers?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [How can I create a window with transparent background with swift on osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531118/how-can-i-create-a-window-with-transparent-background-with-swift-on-osx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get an instance of your application window as follow:

```
guard let window = NSApplication.shared().windows.first else { return }
window.isOpaque = false
window.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Get your window from NSApp (global constant for the shared app instance):

```
guard let window = NSApp.windows.first else { return }
```

Or override `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` and access your view's window property.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    view.window?.isOpaque = false
    view.window?.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```