# NSWindow with round corners in swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want a window with a rounded corners. But I get a white spot in every corner.

**Code:**

```
let effect = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
effect.blendingMode = .behindWindow
effect.state = .active
effect.material = .dark
effect.wantsLayer = true
effect.layer?.cornerRadius = 15.0
window.contentView = effect
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
window.titleVisibility = .hidden
```

**Output:**

[image]

How to get rid of those white spot in the corners?

Comment: Search for borderless window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754898/how-to-make-window-transparent-in-osx-swift/42755175#42755175

Comment: @LeoDabus can you help me with this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774922/how-to-add-buttons-when-nsvisualeffectview-is-used

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also add this code to your code

```
window.isOpaque = false
window.backgroundColor = .clear
```

I don't have my machine to check but once I had the same issue and I think I resolved it by using above code. I will check when I get back to my machine.

Give it a shot and update me.

Comment: can you help me with this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774922/how-to-add-buttons-when-nsvisualeffectview-is-used

Comment: I used this and it works great. However, there is still a very thin line at the top corners of the window that I cannot get rid of (that's a remaining of the titleBar, despite it is transparent). Note that I cannot use 'Hide Title' in IB ; for some reason (may be because that is within the initial controller of the Storyboard), windowDidBecomeMain is no more called if i hide.