# How to add buttons when NSVisualEffectView is used

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsvisualeffectview

I have created a window using `NSVisualEffectView` to get blur and rounded corners. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42762856/7517228)

The problem is I don't see my button in the window when I have `NSVisualEffectView` code. If I remove the code, the button is displayed. What is going wrong?

**NSVisualEffectView code in AppDelegate.swift:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        guard let window = NSApplication.shared().windows.first else { return }
        let effect = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        effect.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        effect.state = .active
        effect.material = .dark
        effect.wantsLayer = true
        effect.layer?.cornerRadius = 15.0
        effect.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        window.isOpaque = false
        window.backgroundColor = .clear
        window.contentView = effect
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    }
```

I have added some buttons in storyboard. When I run the project I don't see any buttons.

[image]

When I remove everything from `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)` i.e., `NSVisualEffectView` code, I can see the buttons.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I should have corrected you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762856/nswindow-with-round-corners-in-swift) only but I didn't.

You are using Storyboard so why are you creating `NSVisualViewEffect` variable in your code?

Search for `nsvisualeffectview` in the right panel(Utilities panel) where you search for buttons etc. (object library).

[image]

Drag it and resize it according to your main view controller.

To add the blur effect and mode, go to "Attribites Inspector" in the "Utilities panel"

[image]

and set `window.backgroundColor = .clear` and `window.isOpaque = false`

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        guard let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first else { return }
        window.isOpaque = false
        window.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Now you can add your buttons, text fields and run the project. You can see all your added elements.

I hope it helps!

Comment: OMG! Thank you. I was searching restlessly for 8 hours! You saved me.

Comment: @ssh I'm happy to hear that.

Comment: @ssh How can I round the corners of the window using this method?

Answer (score -1):

`window` is above the view you are adding buttons to, so the buttons are below the blurred-out window, and are therefore impossible to see.  Why not add the `visualEffectView` to the same view as the buttons?  You'd need to insert it below the buttons to make the buttons visible.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean, i'm applying `NSVisualEffectView` to `window` and adding buttons on top of `window` through storyboard. So, how can I bring the button in-front? I have experience with web design and in that I usually have `z-index` to place an element behind or in front. But how to do it in cocoa? I'm new to cocoa. How can I insert that view below the button?

Comment: You really _shouldn't_ be adding stuff to `window` at all, and tbh I didn't even know it was possible to do that in storyboard at all.  You really should be adding the visualEffectView and all buttons to a `UIView`, and the standard place for that is the `view` property of a `UIViewController`.  As for setting the "z-index", all subviews of a view in cocoa have an index as well.  So you can say `self.view.insertSubview(button, at: 0)` to put something on the very "bottom" of a stack of subviews.

Comment: I have tried applying the effect to `NSViewController` instead of `window`. Still I can't see the buttons. Can you please show how to do it? I'm new to mac development and I can't get through

Comment: SkrewEverything's answer solved my problem. Thanks for helping.