# How to change the color of the safearea?

Tags: swift

When I'm doing swipe up on my view, the safearea's background is black. How can I change the color of this one?

Before the swipe up :

[image]

When I'm swipe up :

[image]

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42755175/8447312

Comment: Thanks bro but it's not working. Any ideas guys?

Comment: What is this view that you're swiping up? Seems more like some background view's default colour than a safe area's background to me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear with the question but you can change background colour based on scroll offset position.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}
```

Call in your viewcontroller

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: I'm not looking to change the status bar color background but the view at the bottom of the second screenshot in black color to another color.

Comment: can u please add the code I am not sure is that a window or something else?

Comment: let image = self.layout1.screenShot()

let imageToShare = [ image ] // layoutOne[1].imageView?.image ]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

Comment: activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop
]

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)

if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { ( activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
self.view.frame.origin.y = 0 }