# How to make NSView transparent

Tags: swift, macos, nsview

I'm trying to make my NSView transparent. It only has one CALayer with a yellow oval on it. What I need is: to make background transparent not touching the yellow circle.

I'm making macOS app on Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2.1.

my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.wantsLayer = true

    //here I add CALayer and circle filled with yellow
    let radius = 25
    let sunShape = CAShapeLayer()
    sunShape.frame = CGRect(x: 400/2-radius, y: 400/2-radius, width: radius*2, height: radius*2)
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    let oval = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius*2, height: radius*2), transform: nil)
    path.addPath(oval)
    sunShape.path = path
    sunShape.fillColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor
    view.layer?.addSublayer(sunShape)

    //here I try to change background of a view to transparent
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
    }
```

It just doesn't work. It doesn't provide errors, nor does it make window transparent. Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

Update:
I deleted

```
view.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
```

replaced it with

```
view.window?.isOpaque = false
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: A better way to create a transparent CGColor is `CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorClear)`

Comment: You need to set your view window `isOpaque` property to `false`

Comment: @LeoDabus can you please explain how to do this, because I'm a complete noob

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34531259/2303865

Comment: @vadian I got two errors: "CGColorGetConstantColor' is unavailable: Use class var white/black/clear instead" and "kCGColorClear' is unavailable: Use CGColor.clear"

Comment: @rafulin `NSColor.clear.cgColor`

Comment: I updated question, please look

Comment: You need to override viewWillAppear method and set the view window isOpaque property to false. The view window property will always return nil inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for patiently guiding me. I finally managed to do this. If you can, please make an answer so I can mark it as solution

Comment: this is a duplicate of the questionn above you can just upvote this if you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/34531259/2303865